# Force multisite to use subdirectories on previous wordpress installation

Tags: multisite

Is it possible to force multi site to use subdirectories on the previous installation without affecting anything, as I am using godaddy shared hosting and it doesn't support subdomains on multisite on shared hosting.

When I enabled multisite on the previous installation, it is only giving the options to multisite using subdomains & wordpress doesn't support it on shared hosting. Thus, i am unable to get multisite working on my wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convert an existing single-site WordPress installation a path-based Multisite, there's a note on the Codex:

> You *cannot choose **Sub-directory** Install* (for a path-based network) if your existing WordPress installation has been set up for more than a month, due to issues with existing permalinks.

If you want to switch to a Multisite installation, you may need to export your existing content, install a fresh WordPress instance, turn on Multisite, and then import your content back into your new site. If you haven't yet, this would be a good time to thoroughly read [Before You Create a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) and [Create a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

### Reference

- [Before You Create a Network » Restrictions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Restrictions)